# Why some imports contain aliases and subfolder?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

What is the difference between import statements with aliases and sub-paths?

For example, I usually write

```
import RNFirebase from "react-native-firebase"
```

but sometimes, I have seen lines such as

```
import functions from "@react-native-firebase/functions"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`import RNFirebase from "react-native-firebase"`
is import library RNFirebase.

And
 `import functions from "@react-native-firebase/functions"`
is import modules `functions` of library RNFirebase.

More in 'Specific module installation' [here](https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6).

Hope help you.